# Python Logic - Centering text using periods

Tags: python, string, logic

I'm taking [this intro to python course online](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/8-remix/)

The problem reads:

> For this program, the first line of input is an integer width. Then, there are some lines of text; the line "END" indicates the end of the text. For each line of text, you need to print out a centered version of it, by adding periods .. to the left and right, so that the total length of each line of text is width. (All input lines will have length at most width.) Centering means that the number of periods added to the left and added to the right should be equal if possible; if needed we allow one more period on the left than the right. For example, for input

```
13
Text
in
the
middle!
END
```

the correct output would be

```
.....Text....
......in.....
.....the.....
...middle!...
```

the Hint given is:

> For input line length of L, you should add (width-L)\\2 periods to the right side

Here is my code so far:

```
width = int(input())
s1 = input()

periods_remain = width - len(s1)
L = periods_remain
periods_rtside = (width-L)//2
periods_leftside = width - periods_rtside
periods_rt_str = '.' * periods_rtside
periods_left_str = '.' * periods_leftside
line1 = periods_left_str + s1 + periods_rt_str
```

My line1 result looks like "...........Text.." Instead of .....Text....

[It can be run here](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/visualize/#code=width+%3D+int%28input%28%29%29%0As1+%3D+input%28%29%0A%0Aperiods_remain+%3D+width+-+len%28s1%29%0AL+%3D+periods_remain%0Aperiods_rtside+%3D+%28width-L%29//2%0Aperiods_leftside+%3D+width+-+periods_rtside%0Aperiods_rt_str+%3D+%27.%27+%2a+periods_rtside%0Aperiods_left_str+%3D+%27.%27+%2a+periods_leftside%0Aline1+%3D+periods_left_str+%2B+s1+%2B+periods_rt_str&mode=display&raw_input=13%0AText&curInstr=0)

My problem seems to be the L. I'm not sure how to define L. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `str.center` for this:

```
>>> lis = ['Text', 'in', 'the', 'middle!', 'END']
>>> for item in lis:
...     print item.center(13, '.')
...     
.....Text....
......in.....
.....the.....
...middle!...
.....END.....
```

or `format`:

```
for item in lis:
    print format(item,'.^13')
...     
....Text.....
.....in......
.....the.....
...middle!...
.....END.....
```

Working version of your code:

```
lis = ['Text', 'in', 'the', 'middle!', 'END']
width = 13
for s1 in lis:
    L = len(s1)                                    #length of line
    periods_rtside = (width - L)//2                #periods on the RHS
    periods_leftside = width - periods_rtside - L  #peroids on the LHS
    periods_rt_str = '.' * periods_rtside
    periods_left_str = '.' * periods_leftside
    line1 = periods_left_str + s1 + periods_rt_str
    print line1
```

**output:**

```
.....Text....
......in.....
.....the.....
...middle!...
.....END.....
```

Comment: You didn't seem to use the teacher's formula for calculating number of periods on each side? (width-L)\\2

Comment: @StacyM Check the updated answer. Note that `L` is the length of the string according to the Hint, but you assigned it to something else.

Comment: I understand now! Over-engineering on my part. Thanks! Cheers and enjoy your points!

Answer (score 0):

For those still struggling with this tough question, here is my code that works in Python 3 shell, even though it still fails in http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/8-remix/

```
First_line = input("First input: ")
width = int(First_line)

while True:
    s1 = input("Second input: ")
    if s1 != 'END':
        L = len(s1)                                                             #length of line
        periods_rtside = (width - L)//2                                     #periods on the RHS
        periods_leftside = width - periods_rtside - L                   #periods on the LHS
        periods_rt_str = '.' * periods_rtside
        periods_left_str = '.' * periods_leftside
        line1 = periods_left_str + s1 + periods_rt_str
        print(line1)
    else:
        break
```

To get it to work in http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/8-remix/  console, you need to change the first 2 lines to

width = int(input())

and 
s1 to   s1 = input()

and also provide your own test input by clicking on the "Enter test input" button

Answer (score 0):

Just some small changes to the above code and it worked in the grader.

```
     width = int(input())
     s1 = input()
     while s1 != "END":
        L = len(s1)                                                                  
        periods_rtside = (width - L)//2                                     
        periods_leftside = width - periods_rtside - L                   
        periods_rt_str = '.' * periods_rtside
        periods_left_str = '.' * periods_leftside
        line1 = periods_left_str + s1 + periods_rt_str
        print(line1)
        s1 = input()
```